# What is the code for adding the Print icon and functionality to another component in Joomla?

Tags: printing, joomla

So basically, the print functionality does not work by default in Joomla but I've fixed that with some code modifications. However, this functionality is only available in the articles. I have a blog component and I need to make the print button available in the blog entries too

Does anyone knows the code for this? Or knows the files I need to edit?

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print functionality is essentially loading your page with `&tmpl=component` added to the URL. This request variable tells Joomla to load the page, but only with the output from `<jdoc:include type="component" />`. The modules and the rest of the template get hidden.

For the icon, the `com_content` component is actually using its own helper library in components/com_content/helpers/icon.php. You're best off using line 145 from that file:

`JHTML::_('image.site',  'printButton.png', '/images/M_images/', NULL, NULL, JText::_( 'Print' ) );`

This will generate the `<img />` tag for the printer icon.

Comment: Unfortunately when I added this code to the blog component, it did not generate the print button.

Comment: Did it generate any HTML output at all?

Answer (score 0):

A short question related to this topic.
When I use the print button in Joomla 3.x, how can i disable te background.
It makes a waste of ink, and in some cases renders the content unreadable.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, in SO format you should ask a new question and [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431729/what-is-the-code-for-adding-the-print-icon-and-functionality-to-another-componen) this one